# Determine the convergence of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $W_0,W_1,...$ be i.i.d sequence of $\mathcal{N}(0,0.5)$ random variables. Let $X_0=0$ and $X_1,X_2,..$ are defined recursively by 
$$
X_{k+1}= X_k^2 +W_k
$$

Determine in which sense, i.e almost sure/ probability/ mean square/ distribution, does the sequence $X_n$ converge as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Can anyone guide me in this. I feel that they can't converge almost surely. But unable to prove that.

Comment: It seems intuitive to me that they should just blow up to $+\infty$ with probability $1$. Because once $|X_k|$ is more than $100$, say, $|X_{k+1}|$ will be more than $9990$ with enormous probability, etc.

Comment: @Ian: Yeah, me too. If we can prove that they don't converge in probability, that is automatically implied. But how do I prove they converge in distribution ?

Comment: If they blow up to $+\infty$ with probability $1$ then they will not converge in distribution either.